# scrapping data - urlopen error [errno 11001] getaddrinfo Failed

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-science, urllib, urlopen

I getting <urlopen error [errno 11001] getaddrinfo Failed> error while trying to scrape data from a website. Can somebody help me with this error. I am new to Python coding.

here is the code :-

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
my_url=  "https://www.arket.com/en/women/coats-and-jackets.html"
uClient= uReq(my_url)
page_html= uClient.read()
uClient.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure you have internet connectivity from where you're running this code?

Comment: yes and website works all well in another tab